# Can HDMI and DVI output different results?

Tags: display, hdmi, dvi

Can the same monitor output different result when using HDMI and DVI?

My new monitor have different results
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLycg.jpg

I just recently bought a BenQ GW2270 monitor.
Straight from the login screen I see that some blue color are wrong,
producing clear square artifacts.
So I tested it with HDMI instead, and this time the color is right.
I also tested with both the graphics card and motherboard built-in ports, still the same result.
I then bought a second DVI cable, but the artifacts are still there.

Theoretically, DVI and HDMI are both digital, therefore they should give the same results. Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color distortion is due to color bit depth and this is part of the automatic configuration of the monitor. The color bit depth is limited at higher resolutions because you are reaching the bandwidth limits of a DVI cable (or at least this is what was speced out by your monitor manufacturer. Try lowering your resolution to half and doing the same comparison.

Comment: Thanks, I will try later. However I use DVI-D dual-link cable, and uses the standard resolution of 1920x1080 (which single-link should be able to handle). So theoretically this shouldn't happen?

Comment: Unfortunately I already returned the monitor so I didn't have time to test. If a better explanation comes up I can choose that instead.